# Create a new column in a dataframe

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe

```
group<-c("NA","HIGH","LOW","NA","HIGH")
a<-c(14,16,21,34,45)
dataset<-data.frame(group,a)
```

I would like to create a new column called "a_high". If "group" is high I would like the corresponding value for "a" to be returned in "a_high". If "group" is "low" or "NA" I would like "NA" to be returned in "a_high". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you need something different from my answer?

Comment: Nope, that's perfect. Thanks Janos

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
dataset$a_high <- ifelse(dataset$group == 'HIGH', dataset$a, NA)
```

Output:

> ```
> > dataset
>   group  a a_high
> 1    NA 14     NA
> 2  HIGH 16     16
> 3   LOW 21     NA
> 4    NA 34     NA
> 5  HIGH 45     45
> ```